# Good source to learn multithreading with .net?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Can somebody point me to a good site/book/article about multithreading with .net?

I didn't find much info about this...

thanks

Comment: Google "async .net book" and you should see a lot. Make sure you find books in recent years so as to learn the latest (after async/await).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a favourite of mine.

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: Wow, that's powerful resource!

Answer (score 4):

These all helped me:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188793.aspx#fig7

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/volatility.shtml

Comment: +1 for those links.
I would also add to these a video tutorial by pluralsight. It's called "CLR Threading". It's very good for starting multithreading in C# although it's paid.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some articles to get you started:

- [Introduction to Multithreading in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MultithreadingIntro10062005000439AM/MultithreadingIntro.aspx?ArticleID=920ecafc-e83b-4a9c-a64d-0b39ad885705) - provides a good overall introduction to threading.
- [Safe, Simple Multithreading in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx) - this is an excellent series of articles for learning about threading of Windows UI's. You may also want to read [Safe, Even Simpler Multithreading in Windows Forms 2.0](http://www.mikedub.net/mikeDubSamples/SafeReallySimpleMultithreadingInWindowsForms20/SafeReallySimpleMultithreadingInWindowsForms20.htm) to read about BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Jefferey Richter's articles on threading [Power Threading](http://www.wintellect.com/PowerThreading.aspx)